# Sponsoring Standard Visitor Visa when my Tier2 UK Visa is due to expire

Tags: visas

I am employed in an IT company and am currently residing in UK on Tier2 ICT WP which is due to expire by 30-May-2018. My employer will be filing for my WP extension by one more year (till 30-May-2019) in next 5-10 days. Usually it takes about a month to get a decision on extension, after which you go for biometrics and then it takes another 1-2 months to receive the new BRP card - this means that I will have my new BR card (with validity till 30-May-2019) only sometime in June, although I might get a decision letter by May 2018.

I intend to invite my brother and his family to visit UK for 3 weeks in June-2018. I was thinking of sponsoring them, but may not be able to show my visa validity beyond 30-May-2018 as I would not have received my new BRP card when they apply for visitor visa (sometime in mid-May).

I want to know - 
1) If I receive the decision letter of my extension, can I send scanned copy of the same as a proof of my visa validity. Or is the BRP card mandatory to show as proof ?

2) Is it better that my brother applies of his own rather than me sponsoring him. He works in a private company and earns about 1.5 lakhs/month, has a decent bank balance (about Rs 5 lakh) and has a property in his name in India. He will be coming with family (wife-housewife, son-working in private company earning around Rs 30,000 per month, daughter-studying in college)

3) If my brother applies on his own, does he need to show confirmed air tickets and hotel bookings in UK for all the 21 days he would be here. If yes, then can I book the hotels (refundable bookings) from here in his name ? Or does he need to show proof that he only has done the hotel bookings (does he need show proof that he used his own funds for the booking, eg. proof that his bank balance got reduced by the amount that he spent on UK hotel booking ??

Comment: "I was thinking of sponsoring them" -- why?

Comment: It is helpful to distinguish between simply inviting someone or financially sponsoring them. @Rohit which did you intend?

Comment: @Rohit Section4 of the UKVI supporting documents guide states that evidence of flight & hotel bookings is not required unless specifically requested. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make a stronger visa application if your brother and his family can demonstrate that they meet the visa requirements without the need for a sponsor.  Sponsored applications by their very nature are weaker. If they are going to stay with you they can say so in the application (and provide confirmation of this from you) but I would avoid complicating the application process with a sponsorship unless they need your financial support to meet travel and subsistence costs during the trip.
UKVI does not require confirmed flights / accommodation reservations as part of the application process.  https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/614897/UK_Visa_FAQ_South_Africa_PPA_May_2017.pdf. Proving general financial standing and demonstrating a credible intention to return to home country at the end of the proposed visit is key.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91820)

Comment: @WGroleau I’m sorry, I don’t intend to be awkward, but how does my response not answer the OP’s second question (thereby negating his first question)?

Comment: I see know that there are several questions.  You didn't answer the ones I saw the first time.  Sorry.  I don't know whether it is possible to withdraw my vote.  To @Traveller: if your questions must go together instead of separate posts, perhaps you should put them all next to each other and/or highlight them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Just one more question - Is it advisable for by brother to book air tickets and do hotel bookings and show them as proof of travel itenerary, or just having good financial condition is enough (sufficient  bank balance to cover cost of the trip, which I assume would be around 6000-7000 GBP - 2000 GBP for Air tickets for 4 people + 4000 GBP for hotel+food+travel (100 GBP per day hotel cost + 100 GBP per day food and travel)

Comment: @Rohit I’ve updated my answer to add information about travel bookings